Safe to delete snapshot parent?
Can I safely delete the /root snapshot and replace it with its child? Or does the parent snapshot need to be kept around?
Default structure from Fedora, emphasis mine:
$ sudo btrfs subvolume list /
ID 256 gen 1000272 top level 5 path home
ID **257** gen 1000272 top level 5 path root
ID 258 gen 1000243 top level 257 path var/lib/machines
ID 259 gen 476 top level **257** path snapshots/BACKUP_ROOT
ID 260 gen 477 top level 257 path snapshots/BACKUP_HOME

I know I can mount any other snapshot as root. What worries me is the parent/child structure (dependency?). What happens to a snapshot whose parent got deleted?
Or should I just rsync from the snapshot to /root?
